# How do I define style react-native using tyepscript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have the following code in typescript. When I run it, I get the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'sytle' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Read...'.

```js
import React, { SFC } from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const logo = require('../../assets/Logo.png') // tslint:disable-line:no-var-requires

export const NamedLogo: SFC<any> = () =>
  <Image
    source={logo}
    sytle={styles.logo}
  />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logo: {
    width: 88,
    height: 42
  }
})
```

how do I defile style in a SFC in typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your spelling for `style`. You have s**y**tle